# How to create an irregular table using AutoTable

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Using jspdf-autotable. How can I create a table with a column that has a vertical offset compared to other columns? Similar to the length column in this example:

[image: Irregular table]

The table I have today is built with the code below, but I don't know to do the vertical offset.

```
doc.autoTable({
  head: [['Name', 'Slack (m)', 'Length (m)']],
  body: rows,
  tableWidth: doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth() * 0.33,
  startY: 161,
  margin: {left: 400},
  styles: {fontSize: 8, lineWidth: 1},
  rowPageBreak: 'avoid',
  didDrawPage: pageNumber
});
```

Comment: Please, past code, not images.

Comment: Edited @powerPixie

Comment: I tried to understand the question and edited it to hopefully make it more clear what you are looking for.

Comment: @SimonBengtsson That's exactly what I'm looking for, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any way to do the vertical offset by editing the style in autoTable. Instead of creating a table using autoTable I just had to draw lots of boxes in a for loop that all put together would look like a table.

[image]